# Ubuntu remount a root mount that's changed to ro as rw without rebooting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

Because of `errors=remount-ro` an underlying NFS blip caused my root mount to be remounted as read-only. I know there is nothing wrong I need to worry about. How can I remount this as rw without rebooting the server?

Some tests:

```
simon@steve:~$ sudo hdparm -r /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
simon@steve:~$ sudo blockdev --setrw /dev/sda1
simon@steve:~$ sudo blockdev --setrw /dev/sda
simon@steve:~$ sudo hdparm -r /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
simon@steve:~$ sudo hdparm -r /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
simon@steve:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /
mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mount -o remount,rw /mountpoint
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the error `mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected`

Comment: Then your system thinks the device is read only, it's not just the mount.  I would look in the logs to see why this happened.  You can also try setting the block device as read-write, then trying the mount.  `blockdev -setrw /dev/sda1; mount -o remount,rw /mountpoint`.  More info at: [Linux, how to change HDD state from ReadOnly after temporarly crash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/linux-how-to-change-hdd-state-from-readonly-after-temporarly-crash)

Comment: this hasn't worked either unfortunately. did some experiments from the site you linked and output is in original post

Comment: +1 for your profile update, tons of us feel the same way.